# Mathematical notation / formula of a mixed effect model

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, notation, nested-data, crossover-study

I am unsure how to define the mathematical notation of a mixed model of R. 
I built the model in this way:

```
model<-lmer(Response ~ 0+Dose:Substance+(0+Dose:Substance| Subjects), data= DoseResponse, na.action = na.exclude)
```

where doses (series of repeated incremental doses) are nested within treatments (three different substances groups) and treatments*doses are crossed meaning that each combination of treatment and dose is measured in every subject. The model supresses the intercepts ( because the physiological response is starting from zero), but defines random slopes. 
Help with the notation would be much appreciated. 
EDIT:
Here is how the the df looks like with fake data:

```
|Subjects | Substance |  Dose| Response|
|:--------|----------:|-----:|--------:|
|1        |         S1| 0.000|        0|
|1        |         S1| 0.025|        3|
|1        |         S1| 0.100|        4|
|1        |         S1| 0.400|        6|
|1        |         S1| 1.600|       13|
|1        |         S1|    NA|       NA|
|1        |         S2| 0.000|        0|
|1        |         S2| 0.050|        8|
|1        |         S2| 0.300|       10|
|1        |         S2| 0.400|       15|
|1        |         S2|    NA|       NA|
|1        |         S2|    NA|       NA|
|1        |         S3| 0.000|        0|
|1        |         S3| 0.800|        8|
|1        |         S3| 1.300|       25|
|1        |         S3|    NA|       NA|
|1        |         S3|    NA|       NA|
|1        |         S3|    NA|       NA|
|2        |         S1| 0.000|        0|
|2        |         S1| 0.025|        3|
|2        |         S1| 0.100|        5|
|2        |         S1| 0.400|        6|
|2        |         S1| 1.200|        8|
|2        |         S1|    NA|       NA|
|2        |         S2| 0.000|        0|
|2        |         S2| 0.025|        7|
|2        |         S2| 0.700|       15|
|2        |         S2| 1.400|       20|
|2        |         S2|    NA|       NA|
|2        |         S2|    NA|       NA|
```

Comment: How many times the response was measured from single subject? multiple or single? The Substance is categorical variable?

Comment: @ a_ statistician: The response was measured, depending on the value of the response, from ca. 2-10 times, i.e. multiple times for a single subject. The Substance is a categorical variable, defining which substance was given ( three different substances) and the dose is the dose of substance in mg given to provoke a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$Y_{ijk} = \beta_jX_{ijk} + \gamma_{ij}X_{ijk} + \epsilon_{ijk}$$

$i$ index the individual, $j = 1,2,3$ represents the treatment, $k = 1,2,...,n_{ij}$ is order number of measurement for individual $i$ in treatment $j$.

$Y_{ijk}$ is the response of individual $i$ in treatment $j$ at $k$-th measurement.

$X_{ijk}$ is the dose of individual $i$ in treatment $j$ at $k$-th measurement.

$\beta_j$ is the fixed slope of dose for treatment $j$.

$\gamma_{ij}$ is random slope of dose for individual $i$ in treatment $j$. It follows normal distribution with mean 0 and unknown variance.

$\epsilon_{ijk}$ is error term following normal distribution with mean 0 and unknown variance.